# Omniauth NoMethodError in SessionsController

Tags: omniauth

Hi I'm trying to run Railscast's #241 - using Omniauth for twitter - eventually with facebook.The app I'm trying to make will require Facebook's login, but since there is a video on how to use twitter to login, might as well follow it first but I'm bumping into problems.

I keep getting this error after I signed into Twitter. "NoMethodError in SessionController#create" - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass. Here is the related code.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
    end
end
```

I have also set the website and callback link via dev.twitter.com as follows:
website: "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
Callback: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback"

Omniauth.rb in config/initializers:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, 'CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET'
end
```

(I've already provided the consumer key and secret)

Application.html.erb

```
<div id="user_nav">
  <%= link_to "Sign in with Twitter", "/auth/twitter" %>
</div>
```

Added this line in routes.rb

```
match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create"
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :provider, :uid

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["user_info"]["name"]

  end
end
```

I don't know where I went wrong

Comment: is it because I don't have the "twitter" user in my database? but can't be, because I'm logging in with twitter and thus it doesn't need to match my User table. Although I would want to extra their login credentials and put it in my database and create a login for them as well

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the problem. Took me a while.

Twitter changed their "user_info" element into "info"
So instead of

```
user.name = auth["user_info"]["name"]
```

it is

```
user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
```

Next thing to change was in sessions controller from

```
session[:user_id] = user.id
```

to

```
session[:user_id] = user.uid
```